# iOS remove all characters after the last period in a string

Tags: string, truncate, strip, period

I have a string, something like "www.vanityURL.myWebsitesURL.com" and I want to strip off the extension, wether it is ".com", ".net", ".ru", etc... so how can I strip everything AFTER the **LAST** period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
NSString* sURL = @"www.vanityURL.myWebsitesURL.com";
NSRange lastDotRange = [sURL rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (lastDotRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    return [sURL substringToIndex:lastDotRange.location];
} else {
    return sURL;
}
```

Comment: Incredible! I didn't know you could search backwards! Thankyou :)